# How to change build in xCode so that it will be approved?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, build

I am trying to upload second version of my app, but getting this message

Asset validation failed
This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [0.0.1] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [0.0.1]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 4703c705-ac34-4ae5-88b7-aac279628304)

Event though I changed version number in xCode.

[image]

Could someone please tell me where else should I change the version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check under "Build Settings" -> "Versioning" -> "Marketing Version". Also known as the "short" version.

HTH

Comment: And, dont forget Build number, yours is 1, you need to plus this value too.

Answer (score 0):

Changing CFBundleShortVersionString in Info.plist file via VS Code worked for me